# Multiplication in $GF(2^n)$: binary representation and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, finite-fields

Let $\{0,1\}^n$ denote the set of binary sequences of length $n$, and let $\{0,1\}^n\backslash \{ \mathbf{0}\}$ denote the set of binary sequences of length $n$ without the sequence made of $n$ zeros.

Consider $S$ drawn uniformly at random in $\{0,1\}^n\backslash \{ \mathbf{0}\}$  and $X$ drawn uniformly at random in $\{0,1\}^n$. Assume that $S$ and $X$ represent elements in $GF(2^n)$. Let $M$ be the binary representation of the product of $S$ and $X$ in $GF(2^n)$.

**Questions**:

- Is $M$ uniformly distributed in $\{0,1\}^n$ when $S$ and $X$ are independent?
- Is $M$ uniformly distributed in $\{0,1\}^n$ when $S$ and $X$ are **not** independent?

Comment: Hints: A) Review field axioms and their basic properties (such as cancellation law in the multiplicative group). B) Can you build a bias in favor of the choice $X=S^{-1}$ without disturbing uniformity?

Comment: Thank you. For the first question, I would answer yes, by using a generator $\alpha$ of the field and write that there exist $a,b$  such that $S = \alpha^a$, $X =\alpha^b$, and $M = \alpha^{a+b}$, then, a+b mod $2^n$ is uniformly distributed over $\{ 1,\ldots, 2^n\}$ since b is uniformly distributed over $\{ 1,\ldots, 2^n\}$. However, I am unsure how to use Hint A. For the second question, I would answer no by your Hint B since $M$ is constant with $X = S^{-1}$. Is that correct?

Comment: I meant $\{0, \ldots,2^n -1 \}$ instead of $\{1, \ldots,2^n  \}$